# Update product data in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, database

I am trying to update product data programmatically through scripts. The data gets updated in database but not getting reflected in admin panel.
I am using magento 2.3.2
Here is my code

```
 $product = $productRepository->get('my-sku1');
    if($product->getSku() != '')
    {

        echo "Product  found", $product->getShortDescription();
        $product->setShortDescription('This is my simple sample productttttttttt');
        echo "########3";
        $product->save();

    // }
```

Comment: Can you do reindex and flush the cache?

Comment: @SukumarGorai done everything. Still not reflected

Comment: Can you share your code and screenshot where it shows fine and where its not showing?

Comment: Visible here https://prnt.sc/qvgti7 in catalog_product_entity table and not here https://prnt.sc/qvgumi in admin panel

Comment: Can you change the store view dropdown on product edit page to your store view in admin?

Comment: No, not present there also

Comment: Share your code so get the idea.

Comment: Check my question. updated there

Comment: ok share me admin screenshots please

Comment: Visible here prnt.sc/qvgti7 in catalog_product_entity table and not here prnt.sc/qvgumi in admin panel